# Using a custom DLL compiled from rust with a c# Interop

Tags: c#, vb.net, rust, dll, interop

I am trying to call a function from a DLL I have created from Rust in a VB.net WPF project, but am receiving a "System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalDirectiveException: 'PInvoke restriction: cannot return variants.'" error.

Any advice on how to resolve this? I've been banging my head against the wall with this one.

Below are the relevant code segments for each portion of the created interface (VB.net, Rust, C#).

**Flow:**

- Create DLL from Rust code
- Create Interop DLL from c# code generated from the Rust code.
- Add reference to Interop DLL to VB.net solution
- Execute code

**Here is the Code:**

*Rust side:*

```
use interoptopus::{ffi_function, ffi_type, Inventory, InventoryBuilder, function};

#[ffi_function]
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn testfunc() {
println!("message: {}", hello_string(""));
}

fn hello_string(x: &str) -> &str {
    return "hello world";
}

pub fn my_inventory() -> Inventory {
    InventoryBuilder::new()
        .register(function!(testfunc))
        .inventory()
}
```

*Creation of the c# interop with Rust:*

```
use interoptopus::util::NamespaceMappings;
use interoptopus::{Error, Interop};
use std::fs;
use std::path::Path;

#[test]
fn bindings_csharp() -> Result<(), Error> {
    use interoptopus_backend_csharp::{Config, Generator};
    use interoptopus_backend_csharp::overloads::{DotNet, Unity};
    let config = Config {
        dll_name: "testCustomDLL".to_string(),
        namespace_mappings: NamespaceMappings::new("testCustomDLL"),
        ..Config::default()
    };
    Generator::new(config, testCustomDLL::my_inventory())
        .add_overload_writer(DotNet::new())
        //.add_overload_writer(Unity::new())
        .write_file("bindings/testCustomDLL.cs")?;
    Ok(())
}
```

This is the generated Interop code which is compiled to DLL and referenced by the main solution:

```
// Automatically generated by Interoptopus.
#pragma warning disable 0105
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using testCustomDLL;
#pragma warning restore 0105
namespace testCustomDLL
{
    public static partial class Interop
    {
        public const string NativeLib = "testCustomDLL";

        static Interop()
        {
        }
        [DllImport(NativeLib, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "testfunc")]
        public static extern void testfunc();
    }
    public class InteropException<T> : Exception
    {
        public T Error { get; private set; }
        public InteropException(T error): base($"Something went wrong: {error}")
        {
            Error = error;
        }
    }
}
```

*VB.net Class that adds the Rust function:*

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Namespace classes
    Public Class NativeMethods
        <DllImport(".\dependencies\testCustomDLL.dll")>
        Public Shared Function testfunc()
        End Function
    End Class
End Namespace
```

*VB.net code that calls the Rust function, causing the error:*

```
Private Sub B_code_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles B_code.Click

classes.NativeMethods.testfunc()

End Sub
```

Eventually the goal is to pass a string from VB.net to the Rust DLL, manipulate it, then return it to VB.net.

Comment: VB.NET allows omitting the Function return type, defaulting to System.Object.  Which cannot be marshaled as a return type.  It is a rather wild mix of Rust, C# and VB.NET but it looks to me you need to declare it as a Sub, not a Function.

Comment: @HansPassant Oh my! You're right! Classic. Could you post that as an answer so I can accept it? Working with all these languages has my head spinning. Unfortunately theres a singular rust framework I need to use. Thanks!